# Example of .net application using Amazon SQS

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am looking for a sample .Net application that continuously checks Amazon SQS for new messages and when one is found, perform an action and remove it from the queue.

My goal is to have an app running on EC2 that watches my SQS queue for new messages. When one is found, a call will be made to one of several web based APIs and the message will be deleted from the queue.

Can someone point me to an example of something similar ?

**edit**
Would this type of application best be created as a windows service?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) features samples for several [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/), including an *Amazon SQS Sample*, which *demonstrates how to make basic requests to Amazon SQS using the AWS SDK for .NET*.

The SDK is installed via Windows Installer and integrates with Visual Studio; by default, the desired sample ends up in `C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\Samples\AmazonSQS_Sample` and provides Visual Studio solutions for both versions 2008 and 2010.

Comment: No longer appears to be the case.

Comment: AWS SDK for .NET » Developer Guide » Code Examples » [Messaging Using Amazon SQS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/sqs-apis-intro.html)

Comment: The sample code only shows the actual request, not how or where to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows service will be a perfect candidate for this.

The following link from amazon aws has a really good summary of details you need to pay attention to: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-loosely-coupled-scalable-c-applications-with-amazon-sqs-and-amazon-sns/

Answer (score 0):

You could use NServiceBus with its SQS transport for this:
https://docs.particular.net/samples/sqs/simple/

You could host that in a windows service or anywhere you like. That being said, you'd need to take some care with regards to monitoring that service to make sure it stays running.

A simpler approach would probably be using AWS Lambda for hosting your message-processing logic: https://docs.particular.net/samples/previews/aws-lambda/sqs/