# Configuring Amazon SES Feedback Notifications via Amazon SNS in ASP.NET MVC (C#)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Good day!
I'm just started with Amazon SES.
I want use this in my asp.net mvc (C#) website.

I download and install AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio, create AWS simple console application.
So, I have sample code that can send email, using AmazonSimpleEmailService client.

PART 1:

```
using (AmazonSimpleEmailService client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
{
     var sendRequest = new SendEmailRequest
     {
     Source = senderAddress,
     Destination = new Destination { ToAddresses = new List<string> { receiverAddress } },
     Message = new Message
     {
        Subject = new Content("Sample Mail using SES"),
        Body = new Body { Text = new Content("Sample message content.") }
     }
     };

     Console.WriteLine("Sending email using AWS SES...");
     SendEmailResponse response = client.SendEmail(sendRequest);
     Console.WriteLine("The email was sent successfully.");
 }
```

Further, I must configuring Amazon SES Feedback Notifications via Amazon SNS.
I find nice topic with sample code:

PART 3:
http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxJE1JNZ6T9JXK/Handling-Bounces-and-Complaints

So, I need make PART 2 where I'll get ReceiveMessageResponse response and send it into PART 3.

I need implement in C# this steps:
 Set up the following AWS components to handle bounce notifications:

```
1. Create an Amazon SQS queue named ses-bounces-queue.
2. Create an Amazon SNS topic named ses-bounces-topic.
3. Configure the Amazon SNS topic to publish to the SQS queue.
4. Configure Amazon SES to publish bounce notifications using ses-bounces-topic to ses-bounces-queue.
```

I try write it:

```
// 1. Create an Amazon SQS queue named ses-bounces-queue.
 AmazonSQS sqs = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSQSClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
                    CreateQueueRequest sqsRequest = new CreateQueueRequest();
                    sqsRequest.QueueName = "ses-bounces-queue";
                    CreateQueueResponse createQueueResponse = sqs.CreateQueue(sqsRequest);
                    String myQueueUrl;
                    myQueueUrl = createQueueResponse.CreateQueueResult.QueueUrl;
// 2. Create an Amazon SNS topic named ses-bounces-topic
AmazonSimpleNotificationService sns = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
                    string topicArn = sns.CreateTopic(new CreateTopicRequest
                    {
                        Name = "ses-bounces-topic"
                    }).CreateTopicResult.TopicArn;
// 3. Configure the Amazon SNS topic to publish to the SQS queue
                    sns.Subscribe(new SubscribeRequest
                    {
                        TopicArn = topicArn,
                        Protocol = "https",
                        Endpoint = "ses-bounces-queue"
                    });
// 4. Configure Amazon SES to publish bounce notifications using ses-bounces-topic to ses-bounces-queue
                    clientSES.SetIdentityNotificationTopic(XObject);
```

I'm on the right track?

How I can implement 4 part? How receive XObject?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track - for the missing part 4 you need to implement receiving of a message from the [Amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) message queue you created in step 1. See my answer to [Example of .net application using Amazon SQS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9453211/45773) for where to find a respective example - it boils down to the following code:

```
// receive a message
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest();
receiveMessageRequest.QueueUrl = myQueueUrl;
ReceiveMessageResponse receiveMessageResponse = sqs.
   ReceiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);
if (receiveMessageResponse.IsSetReceiveMessageResult())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Printing received message.\n");
    ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = receiveMessageResponse.
        ReceiveMessageResult;
    foreach (Message message in receiveMessageResult.Message)
    {
        // process the message (see below)
    }
}
```

Within the loop you need to call either `ProcessQueuedBounce()` or `ProcessQueuedComplaint()` as illustrated in [Handling Bounces and Complaints](http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxJE1JNZ6T9JXK/Handling-Bounces-and-Complaints).

Comment: Thank you! But I implement receiving SNS notification without SQS. I hope this will work without SQS.

Comment: Hi, I wrote the [Handling Bounces and Complaints](http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxJE1JNZ6T9JXK/Handling-Bounces-and-Complaints) SES blog post. Bounce and complaint processing will work fine if you use HTTP/S endpoints instead of SQS. However, SNS [cannot guarantee delivery to HTTP/S endpoints](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#49) because of internet issues. I used SQS in the sample code because SNS to SQS delivery has significantly higher reliability, and bounce and complaint processing is typically considered a critical operation.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had to tackle this problem and I couldn't find a good code example on how to handle the SNS bounce notification (as well as topic subscription request) from a .Net website. Here's the Web API method I came up with to handle SNS bounce notifications from Amazon SES.

The code is in VB but any online [VB to C# converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) should be able to easily get it converted for you.

```
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports Amazon.SimpleNotificationService

Namespace Controllers
    Public Class AmazonController
        Inherits ApiController

        <HttpPost>
        <Route("amazon/bounce-handler")>
        Public Function HandleBounce() As IHttpActionResult

            Try
                Dim msg = Util.Message.ParseMessage(Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)

                If Not msg.IsMessageSignatureValid Then
                    Return BadRequest("Invalid Signature!")
                End If

                If msg.IsSubscriptionType Then
                    msg.SubscribeToTopic()
                    Return Ok("Subscribed!")
                End If

                If msg.IsNotificationType Then

                    Dim bmsg = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Message)(msg.MessageText)

                    If bmsg.notificationType = "Bounce" Then

                        Dim emails = (From e In bmsg.bounce.bouncedRecipients
                                      Select e.emailAddress).Distinct()

                        If bmsg.bounce.bounceType = "Permanent" Then
                            For Each e In emails
                                'this email address is permanantly bounced. don't ever send any mails to this address. remove from list.
                            Next
                        Else
                            For Each e In emails
                                'this email address is temporarily bounced. don't send any more emails to this for a while. mark in db as temp bounce.
                            Next
                        End If

                    End If

                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                'log or notify of this error to admin for further investigation
            End Try

            Return Ok("done...")

        End Function

        Private Class BouncedRecipient
            Public Property emailAddress As String
            Public Property status As String
            Public Property diagnosticCode As String
            Public Property action As String
        End Class

        Private Class Bounce
            Public Property bounceSubType As String
            Public Property bounceType As String
            Public Property reportingMTA As String
            Public Property bouncedRecipients As BouncedRecipient()
            Public Property timestamp As DateTime
            Public Property feedbackId As String
        End Class

        Private Class Mail
            Public Property timestamp As DateTime
            Public Property source As String
            Public Property sendingAccountId As String
            Public Property messageId As String
            Public Property destination As String()
            Public Property sourceArn As String
        End Class

        Private Class Message
            Public Property notificationType As String
            Public Property bounce As Bounce
            Public Property mail As Mail
        End Class

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem today. I solved the problem by configuring a WebHook (https) in the SNS configuration. On the webserver i process now the events. I have create a nuget package with the logic.

My Code - [Nager.AmazonSesNotification](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.AmazonSesNotification)

```cs
[Route("SesNotification")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SesNotificationAsync()
{
    var body = string.Empty;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    var notificationProcessor = new NotificationProcessor();
    var result = await notificationProcessor.ProcessNotificationAsync(body);

    //Your processing logic...

    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
}
```